# Utilizing the next pointer in Doubly Linked Lists

Tags: c++, list, search, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I'm having a problem specifically with a search, select, and replace function. Particularly, a certain line of code is causing my program to crash (it just begins to run then crashes, saying the execution has failed). Here's the code for my search function (the same line of code is making the program crash):

```
unsigned int DoublyLinkedList::search(DataType value) const
{   
    if (size_ == 0)
        return size_;

    else
    {
        Node* temp = head_;

        for (int i = 0; i < size_; i++)
        {
            if (temp->value == value)
                return i;

            temp = temp->next;
        }

        return size_;
    }
}
```

By all accounts, I'm fairly certain this code should work as intended. But it seems the "temp = temp->next" line is making the program crash (running the function without that line works perfectly fine).

I've tried running this in Eclipse IDE, Dev-C++, but both seem to fail. Could there be a problem somewhere else in my code that I'm not thinking of?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Either your `size_` is wrong, or your nodes are linked improperly in another function. Either way, we don't have enough here to say.

Comment: Please provide a [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Because you dereference the null pointer when you use construction temp ->next.
Before this put the if(temp) next do moving